# Encode .NET Byte[] and assign to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc view receiving a List<Byte[]> as the model.  Each byte[] represents a pdf generated via iTextSharp.  I have been trying unsuccessfully to encode and assign to a javascript variable.  I've used btoa(), TextEndoder(), but regardless, when I go to assign to a javascript variable the console shows the error "Invalid or unexpected token".

```
 <script>
        var arr = new Array(@Model.Count);
        var encoder = new TextEncoder();
    </script>

    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
       
        string data = Convert.ToBase64String(@Model[i]);
        string d2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
       
        <script>
            //arr[@i] = btoa(@d2);
            arr[@i] = encoder.encode(@d2);  //ERRORS HERE
        </script>
     

    }
```

Here is the error I get in the console
[image]

When I examine the error in the string itself it's always something like this:
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add JavaScript quotes around `@d2`

Comment: @phuzi   THANK YOU!!!! that was it.  I just needed to have btoa('@d2').